# Adaptec 5805 Raid 5 Offline

Tags: raid5, adaptec

I have an ESXi Server with an Adaptec 5805 Raid Controller,8x 1TB HDDs.
In the middle of the last week I saw that one Disk has an Error (the Controller was beeping and the light on the HDD was blinking). So I shut down all VMs (everything was working fine, with no Errors) and restarted the Sever to enter the Configuration Utility. I saw that the Disk 1 on the Controller has Errors and was shutting down. I Replaced it with a new Disk, but from the same Type. Normally he starts directly the rebuild, but not this time, he does nothing. After this I restarted the Server again to Boot the Storage Manager. Now he told me that all four Raid 5 are Offline! Has anyone an Idea what options I have now? And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Adaptec RAID cards are terrible in every way.  You're probably out of luck... get rid of that horrible card and restore your backups to something that actually works.